# Error in inherits(x, "tbl_df") : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to reproduce a code published at R bloggers, however I have some issues with the data.

This are the packages I downloaded:

```
# Load the necessary packages
# Tidyverse is our rock in data analysis (includes ggplot2)
if(!require("tidyverse")) install.packages("tidyverse") 
# Janitor cleans data like the best janitor out there!
if(!require("janitor")) install.packages("janitor")
# ggsci has my favourite color palettes
if(!require("ggsci")) install.packages("ggsci")
# ggalt is necessary for the dumbbell chart
if(!require("ggalt")) install.packages("ggalt") 
# ggtext allows for great text to include for charts
if(!require("ggtext")) install.packages("ggtext")
```

And here is my issue:

```
# Load the csv data file
df <- read_csv("WomenInGovernment_Data.csv")
```

```
── 

Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
cols(
  .default = col_character()
)
ℹ Use `spec()` for the full column specifications.

Warning: 13 parsing failures.
row col   expected    actual                         file
33  -- 27 columns 1 columns 'WomenInGovernment_Data.csv'
64  -- 27 columns 1 columns 'WomenInGovernment_Data.csv'
65  -- 27 columns 1 columns 'WomenInGovernment_Data.csv'
78  -- 27 columns 1 columns 'WomenInGovernment_Data.csv'
91  -- 27 columns 1 columns 'WomenInGovernment_Data.csv'
... ... .......... ......... ............................
See problems(...) for more details.

> spec()
Error in inherits(x, "tbl_df") : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I downloaded the data from GitHub [1](https://github.com/danderson222/women-in-government/blob/main/WomenInGovernment_Data.csv) as a csv file.

Comment: I tried reading the csv file with tidyverse version 1.3.0 and it seems to work for me without warnings. Could you show what the value of `df` like after the `read_csv` function is called? It could also be that the file WomenInGovernment_Data.csv is updated and not correctly formatted. Have you tried re-download the csv and restart R session (if you're using RStudio) and then rerun the code

Comment: I also have the tidyverse version 1.3.0 and I re-downloaded the file a couple of times because I hoped that that would be my mistake. And I am not using R Studios. 
When I view the the head of my df data I get the table like I should with the right data without any issue. Unfortunately this comment box is too small to show you.

Comment: You can post what your `df` looks like in your question by editing it. There's an "Edit" button on the bottom left of your answer below the `csv` tag. You can click on that to update your answer

Comment: I don't know why or how but the issue resolved itself by retyping the whole code. However, thanks a lot for your support!!